# javac doesn't support the "internalantrunner" attribute

Tags: ant, build, javac

I got the error message above when trying to build the ant build from eclipse and in the command line. I could not find a solution on it on the web. What could be the problem?

-Brevis Iunius

Answer (score 0):

Some glassball guessing:

It looks like you have an `internalantrunner` attribute on your `javac` task element, and this attribute is not supported by the javac task.

If you created your ant buildfile yourself, simply remove this attribute. If it was generated by something else, check the versions of this software.